# Cross-platform Python scanner interface

Tags: python, cross-platform, image-scanner

I'm looking for a library that can interface with scanners on both Windows and Linux, in Python. Is there such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a project on google code: [imagescanner](http://code.google.com/p/imagescanner/)

> The python-imagescanner (old
>   pyscanning) implements an abstraction
>   layers allowing users to scan
>   images/documents from Linux or Windows
>   boxes without the need of write any
>   specific Python code for each one of
>   them.